# Can a Telegram bot create a survey on a channel?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I’m looking to allow members of a TG channel to generate their own surveys and have the bot post those surveys to the channel. Is this possible?

As an extension to this, would it be possible to have the results (votes, not identities) of the survey public on the channel itself and is it possible to have the results private and shared only with the user who envisioned the survey by having the bot message back.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You can use the [native polls](https://telegram.org/blog/polls). The user could send the questions to the bot private chat in a some format (you choose that) and the bot would send it to your channel in the native poll form. Here the documentation: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#poll

In the native polls you cannot hide the results and they are shown in percentage, but you can obtain the number of votes in each option from `voter_count` in `PollOption` object and send they to the channel (public) or to the user (private). Here the documentation: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#polloption